# Populate SQL table in Python depending on the existing attributes in the table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I have created a Table named UserEntry and have populated it with the tweet data. The table is below, so you can see the columns in the table

```
c.execute("drop table if exists UserEntry")
UserEntry = """Create table UserEntry
    (id text, name text, screen_name text,description text, friends_count integer,
    constraint pk_UserEntry
    primary key (id)
    );"""   
c.execute(UserEntry)
```

Now I have to add another column (True/False) in the table depending upon whether “screen_name” or “description” attribute contains within it the “name” attribute.

```
c.execute("ALTER TABLE UserEntry ADD contain text").fetchall()
```

Now I am not sure how to populate the field "Contain". An example of how what the field "Contain" should look like is below:

```
ID     Name       Screen_Name       Description                 Friends_Count   Contain
001    Chris P     Lady Joker   Gossip too good to wait for         234          False
123   Nas Lope     Nas Lope     This is hilarious. very Funny       45           True
256   Marsi        Funny Guy    I am not a good man, Marsi          456          True
256   Neila Pets   PopSugar     Never expect, never assume          236          False
```

Any input will be apprecaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you have to `UPDATE` all the current record with their contains value:

```
UPDATE UserEntry
SET contains = CASE WHEN screen_name LIKE CONCAT('%', name ,'%')
                      OR description LIKE CONCAT('%', name ,'%')
                    THEN True
                    ELSE False
                     END
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99fbd/1/0)

Then to maintain the integrity of the `contain` values whenever new records are inserted or existing records are updated you will need to use `TRIGGER`s:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_UserEntry_BeforeInsert BEFORE INSERT ON UserEntry
FOR EACH ROW 
SET new.contains = CASE WHEN new.screen_name LIKE CONCAT('%', new.name ,'%')
                          OR new.description LIKE CONCAT('%', new.name ,'%')
                        THEN True
                        ELSE False
                        END;
```

And you'll need an identical one for `BEFORE UPDATE` too.

See a [working demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1664b/1/0), note that I do an `UPDATE` on the last row which is why it shows `contains = 1` too.

Since you are using SQLite you can't use `CONCAT()` so instead use `'%'||new.name||'%'`. And since your `contains` column is of type `text` you need to use quoted strings for the `True` and `False` values
e.g.

```
CASE WHEN new.screen_name LIKE '%'||new.name||'%'
       OR new.description LIKE '%'||new.name||'%'
     THEN "Y"
     ELSE "N"
     END;
```

Comment: WOW!! thanks so much for this, I am not very good at SQL and Python, but I do not think trigger will do it, since the table is already populated with everything except the "Contain" column. I need to populate the "Contain" column based on the values in description & screen_name (if they contain the name), and "contain" has to be true/false. We do not populate "Contain" on the update. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Answer updated, you should still create the triggers after the initial `UPDATE`, otherwise whenever data in the table changes you will manually have to `UPDATE` all the `contains` values.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try to use this code. In my case the "Contain" field is text, instead of Boolean, so syntactically am I just supposed to put quotes around "True" and "False" or should there be an equal sign as well. Thanks so much for your help once again.

Comment: No problem, nah no equals sign, just `THEN "True" ELSE "False"` or `"1"/"0"` or `"Y"/"N"` or whatever you want to use. Please accept the answer once you know it works.

Comment: Yes I will. I really appreciate your help. I will try it right now.

Comment: I tried running the code and got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: CONCAT

Comment: Ah its because your question is tagged as both `mysql` and `sqlite3`, I've been testing for `mysql`. You need to replace both `CONCAT('%', name ,'%')` with `'%'||name||'%'`. Updating answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41745/discussion-between-nasia-jaffri-and-oghaza)